# Matlab timer doesnt work in stand alone application

Tags: matlab, timer, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

i have built this application that listens to a certain folder and continuously checks if certain files appear in it. 
once these files appear i activate another function to process them. 
I implemented the folder listener using a Timer object with a fixed rate of 30 sec. 
(i.e - every 30 sec it should check the content of the folder.) 
Everything works great when i run the code from within Matlab, yet when i compile and then deploy the app the timer only executes once and then exits the program.

any idea what can cause this difference between compiled and un-compiled versions?

system is Ubuntu 14.04,

timer object instance:

```
myTimer = timer('TimerFcn',@checkFolderForChanges,'Period',h.listenerInterval,'ExecutionMode','fixedSpacing','BusyMode','queue','UserData',userData);
```

compile arguments:

```
mcc -mv fileWatch.m
```

debug lines i added to monitor the timer, 
from within Maltab:

```
timer running mode: on
timer tasksExecuted mode: 682
timer running mode: on
timer tasksExecuted mode: 683
```

stand alone deployed version (exits after 1 timer task execution:

```
timer running mode: on
timer tasksExecuted mode: 1
vncuser@mathlab:~/visualizer$
```

Comment: I suspect the timer function is crashing - check that everything is compiled correctly.

Comment: what do you mean compiled correctly? i dont get any exceptions when compiling...

Comment: Make sure all the files you need are included in the compiled code - especially all the functions/files that your timer function will use

Comment: yes..all files are there. the Timer is part of the maltab runtime

Comment: May be the program is exiting normally. Unlike MATLAB command line there is nothing to keep the timer alive once the program is done.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the compiled MATLAB program from exiting after a single timer execution, use

```
wait(t);
```

after you have started the timer. This will force the command/terminal window to stay open until the timer finishes (either finishes executing the number of specified tasks or something unexpected causes an error).

Essentially the problem is the compiled program has no command window like normal MATLAB so it closes the window once TimerFcn completes. [See this answer from MATLAB Answers.](http://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/283132-timer-does-not-work-in-the-exe-file#answer_221301)
Using wait is the cleanest way, but anything (such as a while loop) that keeps something happening while the timer waits between executions should work.....